# Why does the hook inside my component have different values and references among its functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently got a project that uses the below component. The problem is that `test_val` is referring to different objects and its value is different among the two functions (`onRequest` and `responseInterceptor`) and its update in one place won't reflect in the other place.

I also tested `useState` instead of `useRef` and again it has different references and even in the next render, its value doesn't reflect the other function.

Also in the parent component, it only gives the value set from one function.

```
//######### define `objectId` to check object's reference
//          (from stackoverflow.com/a/35306050/5371561)
var objIdMap=new WeakMap, objectCount = 0;
function objectId(object){
  if (!objIdMap.has(object)) objIdMap.set(object,++objectCount);
  return objIdMap.get(object);
}

const useHttp = (isDeep = true) => {
  
//######### Definition
  const test_val = useRef(0)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined)
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined)
  
  const onRejectInterceptor = useCallback((type, interceptor) => {
    if (!!interceptor || interceptor === 0) {
      http.interceptors[type].eject(interceptor)
    }
  }, [])
  onRejectInterceptor('request', requestInterceptor)
  onRejectInterceptor('response', responseInterceptor)
  requestInterceptor = http.interceptors.request.use(
    httpConfig => { return httpConfig },
    httpError => { return Promise.reject(httpError) }
  )

  responseInterceptor = http.interceptors.response.use(
    httpResponse => {return httpResponse},
    httpError => {
      if (httpError && httpError.response) {
        if (httpError.response.data.errors) {
          httpError.response.data.errors.forEach(item => {
            toast.error(translateError(item))

//######### Modifier 1
            test_val.current = Math.random(); console.log(`test_val got ${test_val.current} in responseInterceptor with id ${objectId(test_val)}`)
          })
          return Promise.reject(httpError)
        }
      } else {
        console.warn(
          'Error: axios Handler - 2',
          InitialError.response.data.message
        )
      }
      return Promise.reject(InitialError)
    }
  )

  const onRequest = useCallback(
    async (endpoint, payload, baseUrl) => {
      setLoading(true)
      const method = Endpoints[endpoint].method
      const url = Endpoints[endpoint].url
      const responseType = Endpoints[endpoint].responseType
      const isBody = Endpoints[endpoint].body
      const isFormData = Endpoints[endpoint].isFormData
      const payloadData = isFormData ? new FormData() : payload

      if (isFormData) {
        for (const key in payload) {
          payloadData.append(key, payload[key])
        }
      }

      http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] =
        PayloadType[isFormData ? 'formData' : 'default']
      http.defaults.responseType = responseType

      const data = ((method.toLowerCase() === 'get' || method.toLowerCase() === 'delete') && !isBody) ?
        { params: payloadData } : { data: payloadData }

      let resultData = undefined
      try {
        const result = await http.request({ method, url, ...data , baseURL : baseUrl ?? http.defaults.baseURL })
        resultData = isDeep ? await result.data : result
        if (resultData.isSuccess)
          setResponse(resultData)
        else {
          let errMsg = resultData.errors[0] || "UnknownException"
          setError(errMsg)
          toast.error(translateError(errMsg))
        }
      } catch (error) {
        resultData = isDeep ? await error?.response?.data : error?.response
        let errMsg = resultData?.message || "UnknownException"
        setError(errMsg)
        toast.error(translateError(errMsg))

//######### Modifier 2 - Gives the id different than the one given in Modifier 1
        test_val.current = Math.random(); console.log(`test_val got ${test_val.current} in onRequest with id ${objectId(test_val)}`)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
      return await resultData
    },
    [isDeep]
  )
  
  return [loading, response, error, onRequest, test_val]
}

export default () => {
  const [loadingAdd, , , onRequestAdd, test_val] = useHttp()

//######### Always gives the value set in `onRequest`
  console.log(test_val.current)
}
```